# Create spawners that spawn entities with an initial velocity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a spawner (block entity) that spawns entities "launching", i.e., with an initial velocity and rotation. The following command, however, places a spawner that spawns arrows that are initially stationary.

```
setblock ~ ~3 ~ spawner{SpawnCount:1,MaxNearbyEntities:1024,SpawnRange:3,Delay:1,MinSpawnDelay:20,MaxSpawnDelay:20,RequiredPlayerRange:64,SpawnData:{id:arrow,pickup:2,life:1194,Rotation:[0f,90f],Motion:[0.0,2.0,0.0]}} destroy
```

According to [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow#Entity_data), `Rotation` and `Motion` are the correct tags I'm looking for, and I'm also using the correct data types (float for `Rotation` and double for `Motion`). However, arrows coming out of this spawner only gradually falls instead of going up.

Am I missing anything? I'm running Minecraft JE 1.16.4.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the solution u looking for but u could detect when they spawn and then explode a TnT near them to launch them. A command block nearby that ensures that the mobs stay alive and u got a launcher.